# Fetch Entities with Relationship From Array in Core Data

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, core-data, swift

I have an Entity named Image that has a to-many relationship with an entity named Tag.[image]

Let's say I have an array of Tag Entities [tag1, tag2, tag3] 
How can I fetch all Images who's tags contain all of the ones from the array?

Comment: did your try to add a predicate to your NSFetchRequest ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are these distinct cases:

-1. all images where any tag is in the list

```
NSPredicate(format:"ANY tags in %@", list)
```

-2. all images where all tags are in the list

```
NSPredicate(format:"SUBQUERY(tags, $tag, $tag IN %@).@count = %d", 
        list, countElements(list))
```

-3. all images where the tags contain at least all in the list (but maybe there are more)

There are two possibilities for this last problem. One involves subqueries, but you can do it with compound predicates as well.

```
var subPredicates = [NSPredicate]()
for tag in tagList {
   subPredicates.append(NSPredicate(format:"ANY tags = %@", tag))
}
NSCompoundPredicate.andPredicateWithSubpredicates(subPredicates)
```

Comment: So this will filter out all Images that have all the tags from tagArray in their tags set?

Comment: No, with `ANY` the fetch will get images that have at least one tag that is in the list. I changed my code to use `ALL` instead. Now it will fetch images that have tags that are *all* in the list. Or do you want images which have exactly the identical tag list?

Comment: I am getting kind of a weird behavior. By using ANY I am not getting the expected result and using ALL I get the following error: Unsupported predicate ALL tags IN

Comment: I am still getting an error using ALL but I think the subPredicates should do the trick